# Java overriding compareTo method for Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, object, comparable

I am trying to override the compareTo method to be able to use Arrays.sort()
But when i do this it seems like it is not working.

I dont get any error back but i have a tester that tests and gives an error back. I am supposed to compare the 'totalsales' from the items being compared

Here is the compare to method comparing two ItemSales Items

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ItemSales item) {

        return Double.compare(item.totalSales, this.totalSales);
    }
```

Here is the tester testing this, ofcourse theres much more besides this, but everything else works even clone().

```
ItemSales item = new ItemSales();
ItemSales newItem = new ItemSales(10.0, 50, 50.0);
ItemSales secondItem = (ItemSales) newItem.clone(); 
ItemSales[] myItems = { secondItem, item, newItem };

ItemSales[] myItems = { secondItem, item, newItem };

Arrays.sort(myItems);
if ( myItems[0].getTotalSales() == 860.0 && myItems[1].getTotalSales() == 870.0) {
    System.out.println("ItemSalesDemo.main()             - sorted, this is correct");
} else {
    System.out.println("ItemSalesDemo.main()             - ");
    System.out.println("ItemSalesDemo.main()             ------------------------");
    System.out.println("ItemSalesDemo.main()             -         Error        -");
    System.out.println("ItemSalesDemo.main()             ------------------------");
    System.out.println("ItemSalesDemo.main()             - item and newItem should have been equal");
    System.out.println("ItemSalesDemo.main()             - ");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

As you may know i get the "item and newItem should have been equal" error

Comment: You should read the Comparable interface documentation to know how compareTo works

Comment: form javadoc `a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.` it looks like your trying to use `compareTo` a bit like a `equals`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code would work better if you changed it:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ItemSales item) {
    if (this.totalSales < item.totalSales) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if(this.totalSales > item.totalSales){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with your earlier Double.compare() was that you had the parameters in wrong order, it should have been compare(this, item) and not the other way around

Comment: That's pretty much what `Double.compare(totalSales, item.totalSales)` would do.

Comment: True, but its easier to make mistakes when you mix several functions together. Like in this case, the parameters were in the wrong order

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I did this before but i had the numbers backwards. i had 1 where -1 should have been and -1 where 1 should have been. This was way before i did all of these changes. But thank you this worked. I will vote for top answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: They weren't in the wrong order if OP was trying to sort by descending value of `totalSales`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible difficulties in the `compareTo` method:

```
    if (this.totalSales != item.totalSales) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Normally, the `compareTo` method should return `0` if the two objects are equal.  You often hear the phrase, "compareTo should be consistent with equals()", which means that `equals()` should return `true` when `compareTo()` returns `0`, and `equals()` should return `false` when `compareTo()` returns something other than `0`.

As a general rule, `compareTo` should return `-1` if `this` is less than the `item` (the other ItemSales you're comparing against).  `compareTo` should return `1` if 'this' is greater than the other `item`.

The second problem is what looks like a potential infinite loop:

```
    return item.compareTo(this);
```

I like what you have commented out better:

```
    return Double.compare(item.totalSales, this.totalSales);
```

That's more what I would expect from a compare method.

Comment: i have the method just returning 

        return Double.compare(item.totalSales, this.totalSales);

and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as

```
 @Override
    public int compareTo(ItemSales item) {

        return Double.compare( this.totalSales ,item.totalSales);
    }
```

As per your if condition , you are excepting in ascending order. So change the parameters in Double.compare. As others told please read the Comparable spec first

```
myItems[0].getTotalSales() == 860.0
```